# Why does I get duplicate key error on mongo db. model even I don't unique property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My model:

```
Email_Sender: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    Email_Receiver: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    Message: [{
        msg: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        Date: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        },
        Email: {
            type: String,
            trim: true
        }
    }]
```

```
const get_save_chat_emais = new chat({
                    Email_Sender : s_email,
                    Email_Receiver: r_email,
                    Message: [{
                        msg : message,
                        Date : date,
                        Email : r_email
                    }]
                });

await get_save_chat_emais.save();
```

**MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: chat_database.chats index: Email_Sender_1 dup key: { Email_Sender: "abc@gmail.com" }**

- I do not use unique: true but getting duplicate error on email*

Answer (score 1):

Try to check for indexes:

```
db.collectionNameHere.getIndexes();
db.collectionNameHere.dropIndex('Email_Sender_1');
db.collectionNameHere.getIndexes();
```

If it won't work, try to drop your collection or database if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you defined it as unique before, in that case you need to drop the indexes

```
> use chat_database
> db.chats.dropIndex('chats.Email_Sender_1')
```

[See my already data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Ccq.png)

[see also get error on compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iADAA.png)

Comment: i tried but again duplicate error on email

Comment: thats strange, try using compass or any ui app that may help you to debug the indexes easier